# Inserting a string value when deriving a procedure

Tags: postgresql

Unable to figure out the correct syntax for the reusable procedure to execute -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_POST(
p_content IN VARCHAR)
  LANGUAGE 
    plpgsql
AS
    $$ 
DECLARE
    new_summ VARCHAR(15); 
BEGIN
    new_summ := CONCAT(SUBSTRING(p_content, 1,11),'...');
    INSERT INTO POST (post_id, person_id, content, DATE, summary) 
    VALUES(nextval('POST_seq'), nextval('PERSON_seq'), p_content, DATE, new_summ);
END;
$$; 

CALL ADD_POST((nextval('POST_seq'), nextval('PERSON_seq'),'I have nice clothes', 
CAST ('15-JUL-2021') AS DATE), new_summ);
```

Comment: Your procedure only has a single parameter, so you can only pass one value when  calling it.

Comment: passed 1 value, this is error msg -CALL ADD_POST ('I have nice clothes');ERROR:  column "created_on" does not exist LINE 2: ...al('POST_seq'), nextval('PERSON_seq'), p_content, created_on...HINT: There is a column named "created_on" in table "post", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query. QUERY:  INSERT INTO POST (post_id, person_id, content, created_on, summary)  VALUES(nextval('POST_seq'), nextval('PERSON_seq'), p_content, created_on, new_summ) CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function add_post(character varying) line 6 at SQL statement